# While using useEffect and unsubscribe, it gives Missing return type on function warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm using the following useEffect hook and in the hook, I'm setting a listener and unsubscribing to this listener inside a return.

```
useEffect(() => {
        const listener = firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {        
        })
        return () => listener()
      }, [])
```

But it's giving the following warning Missing return type on function warning on this line:
`return () => listener()`

What is the correct way of typing it without disabled something in eslint?

Any help is very welcome!

Comment: `return () => { listener() }`

Comment: I could fix it with the following 
```return (): void => {
          listener()
        }``` 
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

Add **void** in your arrow function declaration after **return**

```
useEffect(() => {
    const listener = firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {        
    })
    return ():void => listener()
  }, [])
```